# getting last 3 matrix fields by date

Tags: matrix, search, filter

So my members update their courses which is a matrix channel field, tis channel field has 2 cells. Date and course name.

what I would like to do is get the last 3 matrix fields by date across all my members then output the name of the person who updated last.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="zoo_visitor" limit="10"}
       {member_firstname}{member_lastname}
      {courses_completed}

      {Date}
      {/courses_completed}
      {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just order the matrix field by the date column in descending order and apply a limit of 3? That would give you what you need.

Comment: Oh, now that i look more closely at the question, that wouldn't work. You'd really need to order the members by the date field WITHIN the matrix field, which you can't do this way.  I suspect you'll need a custom query for that.